# Use Swift URLSession example code on command line tool

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, foundation

I am trying to figure out the *simplest* way to make an HTTP request in Swift 4 from the command line. I have copied this code from the [URLSession programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW2), and added a couple print statements. I can't figure out why the `.dataTask` is not executing.

```
print("Testing URLSession")
let sessionWithoutADelegate = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/") {
    print("Encoded url \(url)")
    (sessionWithoutADelegate.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        print("Executing dataTask")
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else if let response = response,
            let data = data,
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response: \(response)")
            print("DATA:\n\(string)\nEND DATA\n")
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

The objective is to retrieve data from a REST api, but I can't even make a simple `GET` request to work properly...

Comment: Is this in an iOS or macOS app or in a command line application? Or in a Playground?

Comment: This is in a command line application. I tried it in a playground, but it didn't seem to be functioning correctly because it stopped showing values on the right-hand side, even for things like print statements.

Comment: ...Do you have any code after the ending curly brace, or does the program end there?  The `URLSessionTask` runs asynchronously, so if the program ends before it finishes, you'll never see its result.

Comment: add this `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` to the playground

Comment: Adding that still doesn't make the Playground work.

Comment: So how do I make the system wait for the `URLSessionTask` to complete?

Comment: You can start a run loop: `CFRunLoopRun()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out how to make it work using `CFRunLoop`:

```
let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print("Retrieved data")
    CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
}
task.resume()
CFRunLoopRun()
print("done")
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, so no criticism intended (in fact, I’ve upvoted it), but nowadays we’d just use Swift concurrency, as suggested by vadian. This run loop stuff was a necessary evil back in the day when you answered this question, but for the sake of future readers, this would be best considered an antipattern nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays (Swift 5.5+) it's pretty easy with Swift Concurrency, no explicit runloop needed.

```
struct User : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let userId, id: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
}

@main
struct AsyncCLI {
    static func main() async throws {
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
        print(user)
    }
}
```

Caution: The file **must not** be named `main.swift`, the name can be anything else

Comment: I've got this far but now I want to handle progress and I can't figure out how to add it.

Comment: @hippietrail Please ask a question and add the relevant code

Comment: [Modern way for macOS commandline code to fetch data in Swift, with progress notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071929)