# Modern way for macOS commandline code to fetch data in Swift, with progress notification

Tags: swift, macos, https, command-line, progress

Old programmer but new to Apple ecosystem. I want to use the most modern APIs and Swift techniques to fetch some data over https and get progress reports.

Most tutorials and examples I can find use techniques I think are now outmoded such as `RunLoop` or a Semaphore. Or they're for GUI code where there's already a Delegate.

I was able to get this far, to fetch the data using `async`/`await` from inside a struct annotated with `@main` that has a `static` `async` function.

It uses `URLSession.shared.data(for:` so I don't have to supply a Delegate.

I'm not sure if there's a way to add progress reporting to this. Or more likely I need a Delegate. In that case I've been unable to find how to make a simple Delegate just for this minimal use case. Or maybe there's a different way that I haven't found out about yet?

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    func fetchData() async throws -> Data {
        // this is a 1 megabyte text file, big enough for updates
        let url = URL(string: "https://gist.github.com/khaykov/a6105154becce4c0530da38e723c2330/raw/41ab415ac41c93a198f7da5b47d604956157c5c3/gistfile1.txt")!
    
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        return data
    }
    
    @main
    struct Main {
        static func main() async throws {
            do {
                let data = try await fetchData()
                let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                dump(str)
            } catch {
                print("** \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68552757/1187415

Comment: In an `async` environment use `bytes(from:delegate:)` or wrap traditional `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` in a `Continuation` and observe `progress.fractionCompleted` of the task as suggested in Martin's linked question.

Comment: @vadian: Thanks. I just started to write up an answer using `bytes(from:` based on an older question I couldn't find until after posting my new one. I haven't worked with dataTask and Continuation yet. From what I could grok from Martin's linked it looked like they were taking advantage of a delegate already present in their GUI code too?

Comment: To establish the delegate you need a class inheriting from `NSObject` which works against Swift's lightweight semantics. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `async/await` environment a possible solution is a `Continuation` to have access to the data task and to be able to observe the `progress` property of the task.

Replace `fetchData` with

```
func fetchData() async throws -> Data {
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    // this is a 1 megabyte text file, big enough for updates
    let url = URL(string: "https://gist.github.com/khaykov/a6105154becce4c0530da38e723c2330/raw/41ab415ac41c93a198f7da5b47d604956157c5c3/gistfile1.txt")!
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        let _ = observation // to silence a warning
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: data!)
            }
        }
        observation = task.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, _ in
            print("progress: ", progress.fractionCompleted)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Both methods are about the same speed but the `bytes(from:` method is one byte at a time or requires finicky code to report less often whereas the `Continuation` method reports at nice intervals with convenient info available by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not for the first time, I [found a relevant previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69600724/527702) here only after posting a new one despite efforts searching first.

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    func fetchData() async throws -> Data {
        // this is a 1 megabyte text file, big enough for updates
        let url = URL(string: "https://gist.github.com/khaykov/a6105154becce4c0530da38e723c2330/raw/41ab415ac41c93a198f7da5b47d604956157c5c3/gistfile1.txt")!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let (bytes, response) = try await URLSession.shared.bytes(from: url)
    
        let length: Int64? = response.expectedContentLength == -1 ? nil : response.expectedContentLength
    
        print("expected length", length != nil ? String(length!) : "unknown")
    
        var data = Data()
        if let length {
            data.reserveCapacity(Int(length))
        }
    
        for try await byte in bytes {
            data.append(byte)
            if let length {
                print("prog:", data.count, length, Double(data.count) / Double(length))
            } else {
                print("prog:", data.count)
            }
        }
        return data
    }
    
    @main
    struct Main {
        static func main() async throws {
            do {
                let data = try await fetchData()
                let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                dump(str)
            } catch {
                print("** \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this question is therefore exactly a duplicate or not. As it's 2 years old and Swift and the macOS are both moving targets, this might not be either the most modern way or the only way. This is based on [Won](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8813422/won)'s answer but it has a comment that it is slow, so maybe there is a faster way?